# Upload files without restart

Tags: flashair

I'm using the upload.cgi to delete a file from the SD and upload a newer version of that file to the SD, but the device the SD is into still does recognize the old version.

The FlashAir SD seems to cache the old file contents until I reboot it.

I know that writing to one SD card from two devices is a bad idea so I understand why they implemented it like this, but I need to swap a file on the SD without unplugging it from the device ...

Is there any kind of hidden setting, shell, whatever I could use to actually make the card "have" the edited file without unplugging the card?

The device the SD card is in will not write to the SD at all (so, no data corruption due to two devices writing at the same time), but it recognizes when I unplug the SD and refuses to work (because it validates the file on restart or when I re-insert the SD). But I'd like to swap that file "live" without the device noticing anything strange...